# How to set timeout to graphql-client

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js, prisma-graphql

I'm trying to set `timeout` with `prisma-labs/graphql-request`. I've tried the way described here - https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request/issues/103.

```
const client = new GraphQLClient(config.url, {
  timeout: 30000,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
  }
})
```

My compiler complains as timeout is not directly present in Options interface - https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-request/blob/master/src/types.ts#L7.

Should I need to extend the Options interface to use timeout field?

Comment: You could extend it, might be worthwhile doing a [`setTimeout()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) if you're just wanting to wait 30 seconds before initializing the client/GraphQLClient.

Comment: At that, I find it interesting that you were doing the exact syntax in the issue that was supposed to work!

Comment: Its not a wait before initializing client. I meant the timeout while fetching the API call result. Ex: if it takes more than 5 secs, I might want to stop the execution and free resources and show error page to user.

Comment: Ahh gotcha, makes sense, thanks for the clarity!

Comment: What IDE are you using? If you do your compile via command line does it produce a similar error that you are seeing in your IDE?

Comment: Yes, it's compile time error as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you calling this thru regular api for your service remember it might also timing out on your webserver like express or fastify, try to increase all timeouts there as well e.g

```
fastify: {
  trustProxy: true,
  connectionTimeout: 15000,
},
```